# How to make json-rpc calls?

Tags: jmeter, json-rpc

I've looked through previous questions about this but there was no definite answer so hoping someone can help me here.

I want to make a **JSON RPC** call using a Jmeter sampler but I'm not sure which one to use.

The request takes the following shape:

`https://servicename.bla.com.service.dosomething({pass in JSON params})`

Comment: Could you add some code and more details? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is what you are talking about:

- http://www.simple-is-better.org/rpc/#differences-between-1-0-and-2-0

You can use a regular [HTTP sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) with Raw Post Body provided your service uses POST Method (which is what the example shows).

You can add an [Http Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to set Content Type